# Javascript get function by name

Tags: javascript, function

How do I access this function:

```
readURL: function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $input.next('.input-preview').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }

    $(".ImageInput").change(readURL);

},
```

With this:

```
    $(".ImageInput").change(readURL);
```

Before the function header looked like this:

```
function readURL()
```

And it worked, but how I access the other declaration.

Comment: Can you show the full object containing the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readURL` is a property of an object (that you aren't showing). So pass the object name:

```
$(".ImageInput").change(yourObject.readURL);
```

Comment: Yes, but note that the function expects `this` to be properly set (to something)

Comment: @Pointy JQuery passes the `this` binding along if im not mistaken, and the function is being called from a jquery function

Comment: @randy yes good point; looks like it's expecting `this` to be an `<input type=file>` so that makes sense.